# How can I bulk insert records into multiple tables using prepared statement in SQLite?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, prepared-statement, bulkinsert

I first started with the following Poco:

```
public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }        
}
```

And currently have the following bulk insert to load them all up:

```
using (var cmd = Db.Connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Person (Id, FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES (@id, @firstName, @lastName, @age)";

    var paramId = new SQLiteParameter("@id");
    var paramFirstName = new SQLiteParameter("@firstName");
    var paramlastName = new SQLiteParameter("@lastName");
    var paramAge = new SQLiteParameter("@age");

    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFirstName);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramlastName);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAge);

    using (var tran = Db.Connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var id = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            id++;

            paramId.Value = id;
            paramFirstName.Value = item.FirstName;
            paramlastName.Value = item.LastName;
            paramAge.Value = item.Age;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

But I have now modified the Person Poco to include "Addresses":

```
public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long User { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

How can I now bulk insert the Person Poco using the previous prepared statement?

Thanks in advance.